# Visual studio build and tfs build of class project files

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, tfs

net. so having this basic doubt. In C programming all .c files are compiled to get .o file. as output. the object file. Similarly for C# Class files what is the output generated, When i compile as csproj which has only class files, I dont see any dll files as output. Where can I check what is the issue. Should i compile it in visual studio and see if dll is present in my home directory?, or if I build this project using TFS, in the drop folder i see blank. I do not see the dll. Should DLL be created or no?

Comment: Which TFS version are you using? And which build system are you using? XAML or vNext?

Answer (score 0):

dll files will be generated under bin/ folder when you build a C# Class Library project. So you need to check if the dll files can be generated when build from Visual Studio. If yes, then check the TFS build definition to make sure "Copy build output to server" option is checked.